# Firebase to HTML page: how to not print 'undefined' when there is no value in the database

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

I hope I 'm providing all that is needed to explain my issue. I'm totally not good at scripts so forgive me my stupidity ... teach me to get better please. ˆˆ

So you will find my script here.

I want to show all the records that meet the 'today or in the future' date. 
Going well so far.

Now some records do not have the field artists. And then the output is 'undefined'. Is there a way to cover this... just not print anything when the value and the field is not present?

```
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.2.0/firebase.js"></script>


    <script>
    // Set the configuration for your app

    var config = {
      apiKey: "xxx",
      authDomain: "xxx",
      databaseURL: "xxx",
      storageBucket: "xxx"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);

    // Get a reference to the database service

    //var db = firebase.database();
    const preObject = document.getElementById('Agenda');
    const ulList = document.getElementById('AgendaList');

    // Create references

    const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child('Event');

    // Synch object changes

    dbRefObject.orderByChild("Date").startAt(new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10)).on('child_added', snap => {

    var data = [];
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    var JSONValue = snap.val();

    // create a variable that checks wheater or not there is a picture. If there is a picture print the picture if not do not print anything
    var photo = "";
    if (JSONValue['Photo']!==undefined) {
      photo='<img class="photo" src="'+JSONValue['Photo']+'">'; 
    }

    // check the value of the status field. If the status is Cancelled, print the status. else do not print anything
    var status = ""; 
    if (JSONValue['Status']==='Geannuleerd') {
      status='<span class="status">'+JSONValue['Status']+'</span>';
    }

    // check the value of the message field. If the message is nieuwsbericht then do not print the date. Else print the date.
    var date = "";
    if (JSONValue['Message']==='Concert') {
      date=JSONValue['FullDate'] + '-' + JSONValue['ShortTime']; 
    }

    // check the value of the message field. If the message is nieuwsbericht then do not print the date. Else print the date.
    var title = "";
    if (JSONValue['Message']==='Concert') {
      title=JSONValue['Concert']; 
    }   

    li.innerHTML = '<div class="event">'+photo+'<h3>' +date+ '</h3>' + '<h1>' +title+ '</h1>' + JSONValue['Artists'] + '</div>';
    li.id = snap.key;
    ulList.appendChild(li);

    });
    </script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqjtc.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the logical "OR" operator (written as `||`) to conditionally display something else in case `JSONValue['Artists']` is undefined.

```js
JSONValue['Artists'] || ""
```

This basically means "get the value of `JSONValue['Artists']`, or if its value is falsy (undefined, null, empty, zero, false) use an empty string instead".

The relevant line in your code will be:

```js
li.innerHTML = '<div class="event">'+photo+'<h3>' +date+ '</h3>' + '<h1>' +title+ '</h1>' + (JSONValue['Artists'] || "") + '</div>';
```

I've added parenthesis around `JSONValue['Artists'] || ""` to make the order of operations explicit.

You can also use something else as a fallback:

```js
JSONValue['Artists'] || "No artists for this concert"
```

You can read more about logical operators here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

NB: If valid artist names include "" (a blank string), "0", and `0`, this technique may give you unintended results. All of these values are falsy.

In other words, the following code will evaluate to "No artists for this concert":

```js
"0" || "No artists for this concert"
```

To mitigate this you can use the [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing)